# mobile phone geolocalosation and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, geolocation

I am developing web app that will be accessed by smart-phone integrated browser.
In my application I need to calculate the distance between the mobile phone actual (current) location and some other address. Beside that I should be able to find the specific location (shop location for example) that is closest to the user actual location.

Can you give me a clue which js framework can I use? Is there maybe some jQuery plugin that can be helpful?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use this framework : http://code.google.com/p/geo-location-javascript/

It works on most mobile devices.